# Shopify API: is there a way to retrieve a list of orders for specific Order numbers?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I'm using the ShopifyAPI gem to look up orders for a store - I know that I can use this to find all the orders for a store:

```
ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all)
```

And this to find all orders created after January 1st:

```
ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => {:created_at_min => "2012-01-01"}
```

But if I have a list of order IDs like `[1009, 1006]` - is there a way to retrieve the orders for a store having those IDs, or do I need to look them up individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to look them up individually.

```
orders = [1009, 1006].collect {|order_id| Shopify::Order.find(order_id)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get them all at once with the following:

```
ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => { :ids => "1009,1006" })
```